# Android: get WebView width in onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android

iOS has a good rotation methods like willRotateToInerfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. In first one views has old width and height, before rotation..and in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation I can get new width and height. How to do that in Android ? I need to get new width and height of WebView in onConfigurationChanged method is that possible ? or is there another method ?

Comment: what do you mean by `new height and width`? What is the `default height and width` of the webview?

Comment: I mean width and height before I rotate device to landscape, and after

Comment: what value you set for the height and width initially?

Comment: you can get the height and width by ``getHeight()` and `getWidth()`...

Answer (score 0):

you can get the view width using webview.getWidth()

Comment: it returns old values (this means, it returns value that was before configuration change)